# How to prevent here.com api id hijacking?

Tags: here-api

I'm about to use the here.com API. I generated a api_id/api_code for a new App. These two values must be appended to each request to the API and are, if used in a Web App, visible to everyone.

id+code are not bound to an URL like Google API keys, so I don't see any method to prevent anybody to take my id+code and using it for, lets say, scraping tiles. As the API costs money I wonder how I can prevent that?

http://developer.here.com/faqs says nothing about protection of keys and here.com doesn't really seem to want to talk to developers, so I hope this metaish question dosn't get downvoted...

Comment: Can't you deactivate the app_id at any time? So you could do this if it was accessed maliciously to stop requests.  If you make your requests over https this will make it more secure as well.

Comment: Sure, but that my be waaaay too late. https doesn't help, the app_id+app_code is inherently in the source code.

Comment: If your code is a Web App on a server, how will a user be able to see your tokens? Is your source code public or something?

Comment: It's not server side, it's client side code, fetching tiles from the tile server.

Comment: If the App_Id/Code have to be hidden in javascript try Javascript Obfuscator, If there are http get requests however internally to API calls then the details could be still vulnerable. 

The Here API should be working on implementing an additional check which would restrict usage of the credentials from a domain.

Comment: If it's client side, you can use any browser to look at the GET request to the server and look at the IDs in the headers. My only suggestion is to build a server-side applet which can make the request for you with the headers, and you call your applet from the client.

Comment: @Spork: The API calls are made by the JS-Library of here.com. Proxying the calls is even forbidden by ToS as far as I understand. I really appreciate your suggestions, but there's no way hiding the id/code pair and I'm not really searching for a work around.

Comment: @Jithin Krishnan: The calls can be simply seen by taken a look into the Network Panel of your favorite Browser. So hiding the id/code is not an option. I'm not really searching for a work around, there must be some official way, otherwise this would be quite an API design error. I can't image that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your HERE Developer Dashboard, when you navigate to a project and view your JavaScript / REST tokens, there is a checkbox that says "Secure app credentials against a specific domain".

https://developer.here.com/projects

By locking the tokens to a particular domain or set of domains, they will be protected from malicious users. If someone steals your tokens, they won't be able to use them because the requests need to come from your domain.

Hopefully that helps.

Best,

Comment: I guess this feature was added sone time in the last 3 years, as I can't recall seeing the checkbox. So thanks for the update!

Comment: @Nic Raboy that does not work for me. I'm on a Freemium plan and I added a domain to "Secure app credentials against a specific domain" in the "JavaScript/REST" section, yet I am able to move my code to a host with a completely different domain and it works. Do I miss something?