# Map Tile Request Security

Tags: here-api

My team is concerned about the security of the Map Tile API requests.  You are required to put the `app_id` and `app_code` as URL parameters, which means they are available to anybody that looks.  HEREMaps allows for securing against specific domains, but these are easily forgeable using HTTP Host headers.  Are there any better ways to secure the private keys for the app to prevent unauthorized API calls?

Comment: Similar unanswered question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919116/how-to-prevent-here-com-api-id-hijacking?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of Authentication tokens or API Keys the credentials can be secured in a better way now. You can generate/delete the keys and tokens from the HERE Developer portal dashboard.